# ios app crashes with no error and no crash report

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, core-data, crash

I am currently importing all the facebook birthdays and inserting them in core data,then i sort them according to the latest bday's(fetching and sorting).
When i use facebook to sync and get all the contacts,my app retrieves all the contacts perfectly,but after it receives the contacts it soon crashes..

i tried using zombie objects.

i tried leaks.

i tried adding an exception in exception navigator.

i synced my ipod with itunes went to library and device logs but couldnt find any file which says low memory issue or something that sorta.

i am confused because the reason for the crash doesnt show up,it simply crashes and when i open my app again i can see all the contacts imported from facebook

there is no lldb in the debugger window,when i change it to gdb,i can see gdb but when i use backtrace(bt) it say "No Stack"

i also noticed there is one thing i.e if there are too many contacts my app crashes and if there are less contacts it works normally.

what can be the problem? does it crash because of a memory issue?
how am i supposed to know what is causing the crash?

thanks

Comment: is it repeatable ? does the same behaviour happen in Debug AND Release build configuration ? If using debug, check all logging statements that occurs as part or as a result of that specific use case. You could have some warning there that was overlooked.

Comment: com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.***.***[0x589e][2041]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.***.***[0x589e]) Exited: Killed: 9
thats what happens in device logs so mostly related to memory issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your app is most likely being terminated due to low memory.

The best thing is to look at the device console using Xcode's Organizer:

[image]

If iOS is running out of memory and killing your app, you should see something like this:

```
<Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
<Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.yourapp[0x6337]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

You should use the Activity Monitor in Instruments to see how much memory your application is using.

You can also use the Memory Monitor instrument and enable graphing of "Physical Memory Free". If you see the graph approaching 0 before your crash you can be pretty sure it's a memory issue.

[image]

Comment: Note that even if you are using a crash reporter like crashlytics, you won't get any reports if the app was terminated due to memory.

Comment: @Mike Weller You were right,it is a memory issue just after it crashes the log says this                                              com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.***.***[0x589e][2041]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.***.***[0x589e]) Exited: Killed: 9            thanks for the help,just wondering how do i get the individual memory monitor in the snapshot you have provided above

Answer (score 0):

Try to put some code for memory releasing into viewDidUnload. For example, if you create a link between code and xib using mouse then xcode generates code for current element automatically.

Comment: `viewDidUnload` is deprecated and no longer called in iOS6. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

Comment: Since you have to change the code for iOS6, just implemented in a way that works for both.